# How to find same css libarary already enqueued by other plugin or theme using wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using animate.css popular library for animation in my plugin.
How to know same animate.css library exits already in page by other plugin or theme. 
I know CSS identifier always remain unique like `my-plugin-animate-css`
Then how find the existence of same css or js file?

Comment: @purvik7373 yes, I checked. I think your code check all sources whether that ccs file exists on current page or not. If foo plugin has animate css file but not render foo shortcode on that current page where bar shortcode rendering using bar plugin, then bar plugin fails to enqueue css file.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'check_font_animate', 99999);

function check_font_animate() {
  global $wp_styles;
  $srcs = array_map('basename', (array) wp_list_pluck($wp_styles->registered, 'src') );
  if ( in_array('animate.css', $srcs) || in_array('animate.min.css', $srcs)  ) {
    /* echo 'animate.css registered'; */
  } else {
    wp_enqueue_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/animate.css' );
  }
}
```

Would you please try above code? I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: Hi @purvik7373, I checked your code. Not working for me. This code is not checking on current page file existing.